# Subversion import

Tags: svn, setup-project

I have been working on a [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) project, and I decided that it needed some version control. I have an SVN server running on another machine, and I wanted to import that code into my SVN repository. I am developing on [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) and my SVN server is a remote OS X machine.

I went into my Django project on my development machine, `~/django_projects/myproject`, and ran the following command:  `svn import svn+ssh://user@IP.ADDRESS/path/to/svn/repo`.  The result was a whole bunch of files that were added.

Then I modified a couple of files and tried to do a check in:  `svn ci`.

That command gave the following error message:  `svn: 'path/to/svn/repo' is not a working copy`.

What did I do wrong? How do I get my stuff checked into SVN so that I can do proper version control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `svn import` doesn't create a working copy. To fix this, perform these steps:

- first back up your modified files, just in case.
- Run `svn co --force svn+ssh://user@IP.ADDRESS/path/to/svn/repo/path/to/import /path/to/wc` where `path/to/wc` is the root where you want to create your working copy. This checks out the path in the repository to the path you specify as working copy location. The `--force` parameter will continue checking out even if file present in the repository are already in the working copy. It will not overwrite them
- Run `svn status /path/to/wc` to verify the files indicates as modified are the ones you meant to change
- Run `svn ci`

Comment: Small point of confusion, the remote svn repository has a different name than the local directory.  SVN Co wants to build a local directory with the same name as the repository.  Can you make svn co to a custom or existing directory name?

Comment: **Synopsis**

svn checkout URL... [PATH]
 **Description** 

Check out a working copy from a repository. If PATH is omitted, the basename of the URL will be used as the destination. If multiple URLs are given each will be checked out into a subdirectory of PATH, with the name of the subdirectory being the basename of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The hint is in the spec: [After importing data, note that the original tree is *not under version control.* To start working, you still need to `svn checkout` a fresh working copy of the tree.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html)